# Experimental observation of non-perturbative effects

Tags: quantum-field-theory, non-perturbative

Many quantum field theories come with non-perturbative objects such as solitons and instantons, and non-perturbative effects such as the Schwinger effect. However, it is hard to find any review on experiments that directly observed such non-perturbative physics. Is there any experiments that were conducted or to be conducted which aim to observe non-perturbative effects?

Comment: Look around you... the entire universe is one giant "non-perturbative effect". Perturbation theory has nothing to do with nature, it's just the poor man's math at work.

Comment: @CuriousOne yeah, but thats hardly evidence to the skeptical mind.  That is, one doesn't know a priori the world can't be described perturbatively, it would be nice to see non-perturbative theory at play experimentally.

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird: If you want to make a sport out of perturbation theory, nothing to stop you. Before you do, though, try to solve the three body problem non-perturbatively. ;-)

Comment: This post (v1) seems to be a list question.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to make solitons in water. See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MADng1fqECY) and the video coming after it with the bubbles. They are the [nonlinear solutions](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/physik/KSND/abb/node6.html) of the differential equations governing flow.Also I recomend the one with [bubbles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ederft9dkag) .

[Ball lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning#Soliton_hypothesis) is proposed to be a soliton solution.